# firebase multi-location updates user authentication and database

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a Form to signup new User with email, password, full name and phone number.

I can use `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword` to create new user if successfully. Then I use `firebase.database().ref('users/..').set(..)`to save fullname and phone number to firebase database.

But If the saving processing to database occur error (By rule write:false for example), I STILL have an user Identifier created in User Authentication. So an user exist without phone number and full number.

How can I can multi-location insert user authentication and database. If one of these two failed firebase auto reject inserting new identifier and inserting into database. (The processing only return success if both success).

Answer (score 2):

**There is no way to make the combined Auth and Database operation atomic. If you want to be atomic, you should use only one service: the database *or* authentication.**

To make this atomic you could pass username, password, full name, and phone number to a HTTP function in Cloud Functions. This then [creates a user with the email and password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user), then writes the full name and phone number to the database.

But note that this still isn't guaranteed to be atomic: the same glitch that you're anticipating on the phone, could happen on the server. While chances are much smaller, there's no guarantee.

This means you'll need to make sure that your code is robust enough to handle cases where the full name and phone number are missing. And if you need to do that in the server-side case, it will also work the same if you'd leave the cross-product code on the client.