# How to complete Firebase Storage Task and Firestore Task in the same time?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I'm using:

```
ref.putFile(file).addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {
    ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(uri -> {
        String downloadUrl = uri.toString();

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("profilePic", downloadUrl);
        uidDocRef.update(map);
    });
});
```

To upload an image to Firebase Storage. Once it is successfully added, I use the `downloadUrl` to update user profile.

The problem is when I get an error when trying to write to Firestore. The image gets added but the corresponding url not. I would like to do something like simultaneous updates, which are made atomic: either all updates succeed or all updates fail. How to do this?

Comment: if error occurs on `FireStore` you can Delete that image from `FirebaseStorage`

Comment: @AliAhmed Yes, I thought about this but why to perform a write and a delete operation for a single failure? Is there a way to make it simultaneously, either all succeed or all fail?

Comment: [loana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7919372/ioana-p) i don't know. i do like this. We have to upload the image to Storage first to get its URL then start the FireStore or FirebaseDatabase part. so if Database creates any problem we should delete that image

Comment: @AliAhmed Thanks Ali but I would like to find a solution as explained above, without the need to upload an image, that can be deleted later because of a failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These operations span different services, possibly even different availability zones. There is no way to make them atomic.

Although you can definitely reduce the risk by taking Ali's advice and rolling back from the client, there is no way to make these operations atomic. But at some point there will be a failure that the client can't roll back

The most common approach for the inevitable failures is to make your code robust again failure of the later operations, and perform occasional cleanup.

Also see:

- [firebase multi-location updates user authentication and database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46336817/209103), which covers a similar scenario for Firebase Authentication and the Realtime Database.

Comment: Thank you Frank you for your response. Do you think that `Tasks.whenAllComplete(firebaseStorageTask, firestoreTask)`, make any sense in this case?

Comment: Since writing the URL to Firestore, requires getting the URL, which requires having uploaded a file, they're actually a sequence of tasks, not parallel tasks. So I'd use `continueWith` for that.

Comment: This what I was looking for. Thank you so much Frank!!